# Disable specific <h:selectOneRadio> items

Tags: jsf, disabled-input, selectoneradio

I have 5 radio buttons in my form, selecting one and proceeding takes me to a form that the user need to fill up. Now out of these 5, I have not yet finished 2 of the forms that these radio buttons take me. So I wanted to disable the radio buttons which donot have the forms ready.

How I solve it now: if a user selects one of these radio buttons that donot have a form ready, it says "Page under construction" but I want to disable them completely so that no one selects it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [`f:selectItems`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html), use the [`SelectItem` constructor taking the `disabled` argument](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html#SelectItem%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

```
public class Bean {
    private List<SelectItem> selectItems;

    public Bean() {
        selectItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem(1, "Form 1", null, false));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem(2, "Form 2", null, false));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem(3, "Form 3", null, false));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem(4, "Form 4", null, true));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem(5, "Form 5", null, true));
    }

    // getter for selectItems field ...
}
```

Or, if you're using [`f:selectItem`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/selectItem.html), use the `itemDisabled` attribute.

```xml
<f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Form 1" itemDisabled="false" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Form 2" itemDisabled="false" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Form 3" itemDisabled="false" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="Form 4" itemDisabled="true" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="Form 5" itemDisabled="true" />
```

Comment: how will I take care of it in my case? my radio buttons appear from the database. I am not sure how to utilize your suggestions

Comment: As stated in my answer, use the `SelectItem` constructor which takes an extra `disabled` argument which you can set with `true` or `false`. You don't need *exactly* this code. It's just a basic example to illustrate the idea. You can always populate it dynamically, as long as you use the right constructor.