# Hide specific <h:selectOneRadio> items

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectoneradio, rendered-attribute

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391571/disable-specific-hselectoneradio-items)  related question. how ever i do not want to disable instead i need to hide. seems there is no render property for select one radio items. how can i achieve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally render an f:selectItem tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932034/how-to-conditionally-render-an-fselectitem-tag)

Comment: Deleted my answer because question is a duplication. Just want to add that you can use `f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}"` and conditionally filter your `List<SelectItem>` within the Java bean before returning it in `getOptions()` or during bean construction.